# Writing python decorators with "with"

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a decorator that can be used with `with` keyword.

```
# regular code ...
with my_exception_handler():
    # dangerous code ...
# regular code ...
```

And my_exception_handler would receive a function and wrap it in a huge try-except.

I want to make it a decorator/wrapper because it's a lot of code that I don't want to copy-paste. I can't figure out where to start. I wrote a regular decorator and it works on functions, but not on intermediate chunks of code.

Comment: That’s not a decorator; it’s called a “context manager”. Looking that up should give plenty of examples.

Comment: That isn't a decorator, it's a context manager.  A decorator is something you apply with the `@deco` syntax.  Can you give an actual example of what you want your function to do?

Comment: Thanks! Didn't even know how to search for it. I was trying to emulate decorator functionality for a chunk of code that's not a function.

Comment: Apparently there is such thing as a bad question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing that you use with `with`, is a context manager not a decorator—those are 2 completely different things.

- See http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html for how `with` and context managers work.
- See https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators for decorators.

EDIT: see kindall's post for a good example on how to write a simple context manager without having to use a full-fledged class; I didn't have time to amend my answer with such an example :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a context manager, not a decorator. You can very easily do what you want to do using the `contextlib.contextmanager` decorator.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def my_exception_handler():
     try:
         yield          # execute the code in the "with" block
     except Exception as e:
         # your exception-handling code goes here
         print e

# try it out
with my_exception_handler():
    raise ValueError("this error has value")
```

Comment: I was going to edit my post to include an equivalent snippet but my GF dragged me away from the laptop :P

Answer (score 0):

After learning about context managers I took an [extended traceback function](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52215-get-more-information-from-tracebacks/) and turned it into a decorator and a context manager with a few snippets below:

```
def traceback_decorator(function):

    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):

        try:
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            print_exc_plus()


def traceback_wrapper(function=None, *args, **kwargs):

    context = _TracebackContext()

    if function is None:
        return context

    with context:
        function(*args, **kwargs)

class _TracebackContext(object):

    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        if exc_type:
            print_exc_plus()
```